# Unpack a shell archive (.shar file)

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, archive

I have a shell script.

How can i remove anything before # this line

Everything before the # should be deleted.

The script is too long to delete it manually.

How can I do that automatically?

http://www.openbsd.org/anoncvs.shar

https://github.com/nakj/openbsd-www-ja/blob/master/anoncvs.shar

Comment: At least show some data, or your script

Comment: Are you asking an editor question?

Comment: On gnu/linux see `sharutils`, `man unshar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file you linked to, you don't actually need to delete anything; just save it somewhere, and run

```
sh anoncvs.shar
```

to extract its contents.

The comment instructing you to delete everything before "this line" is there as a preventative measure, in case the file ends up included somewhere else. Such files are known as [shell archives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar) and would commonly be found in Usenet posts, where the comment makes sense: users would save the whole post to a file (this was before MIME attachments), and edit that file before extracting its contents.